# TextView gravity does not work in my custom AdapterView

Tags: android, textview, viewgroup

I have a view extends AdapterView and set data with an ArrayAdapter.
Here's my ArrayAdapter

```
ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, string_array, R.layout.action_bar_simple_spinner_item);
```

A textview in my layout, but gravity attribute does work. No text show in my textview. But if I remove attribute, text shows.

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@android:id/text1"
      style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="123"
      android:textSize="16dip"
      android:textColor="@color/black"
      android:gravity="center"/>
```

[image]

In my AdapterView, I override onMeasure and onLayout. Here's my code:

```
@Override
protected void measureChildren(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    final int size = getChildCount();

    int height = getHeight();
    int count = getChildCount();

    Log.d(TAG, "measureChildren count: " + count);
    if (count == 0) {
        return;
    }
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        View child = getChildAt(i);
        measureChild(child, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(itemWidth, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
    }
    invalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    Log.d(TAG, "onMeasure widthSize: " + widthSize + " heightSize: " + heightSize);
    setMeasuredDimension(widthSize, heightSize);
    measureChildren(widthSize, heightSize);
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
    removeAllViewsInLayout();
    int size = mAdapter != null ? mAdapter.getCount() : 0;
    Log.d(TAG, "onLayout size: " + size);
    Log.d(TAG, "l: " + l + " t: " + t + " r: " + r + " b: " + b);
    if (size == 0) return;
    ...
    int left = l;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        Log.d(TAG, "left: " + left);
        View child = obtainView(i);

        child.layout(left, 0, left + itemWidth, mHeight);
        addViewInLayout(child, i, i < mLp, false);
        left += itemWidth;
    }
    invalidate();
}

@Override
public void setAdapter(Adapter adapter) {
    mAdapter = adapter;
    if (mAdapter.getCount() > 0) {
        if (mSelectedPosition == INVALID_POSITION) {
            mSelectedPosition = 0;
        }
    }

    int size = mAdapter != null ? mAdapter.getCount() : 0;
    if (size == 0) return;
    ...
    mLp.width = itemWidth;
    Log.d(TAG, "setAdapter size: " + size);
    requestLayout();
    invalidate();
}
```

Some log:

```
01-19 10:16:55.280 D/MyView(30120): setAdapter size: 3
01-19 10:16:55.320 D/MyView(30120): onMeasure widthSize: 1080 heightSize: 128
01-19 10:16:55.320 D/MyView(30120): measureChildren count: 0
01-19 10:16:55.340 D/MyView(30120): onMeasure widthSize: 1080 heightSize: 128
01-19 10:16:55.340 D/MyView(30120): measureChildren count: 0
01-19 10:16:55.341 D/MyView(30120): onLayout size: 3
01-19 10:16:55.341 D/MyView(30120): l: 0 t: 168 r: 1080 b: 296
01-19 10:16:55.342 D/MyView(30120): left: 0
01-19 10:16:55.342 D/MyView(30120): left: 360
01-19 10:16:55.343 D/MyView(30120): left: 720
01-19 10:16:55.350 D/MyView(30120): onDraw
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `layout_gravity`, not `gravity`

`layout_gravity` refers to how a `View` relates to its containing `ViewGroup` whereas `gravity` applies to the contents of that view.

Along those lines, you could alternatively continue using `gravity` but set the `layout_width` of the `TextView` to `match_parent`. To be certain what is the best solution, I would need to see more of your layout XML

Comment: I want text display in the center of the textview, not textview display in the center of my viewgroup.

Comment: In that case the second/alternative solution I provided would do the trick. By using a width of wrap content, you are not giving the view any extra room to center the text in. The bounds of the view are "shrink-wrapped" around the text. Once you change the view to be wider (with match_parent, a layout_weight, or a specific width measurement), you will see that the text stays centered.

Comment: I measure child with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY. I still replace wrap_content with match_parent, but still no text in the textview.